# Java - IF statement treats value as NULL even though it isn't when checking in debug

Tags: java, spring, if-statement, null, boolean

This is a strange one so any help would be appreciated.

I'm working on a Spring Batch job that sends transactions to a Kafka topic and when successful the status code is returned as a String: "C". There's a check for if this status code is null and if so it will give an appropriate error message as below to be outputted onto a table later on.

```
            if (kafkaWriter.getKafkaStatusCode() == null)
            {
                messagingResultCode = CommonConstants.KAFKA_NULL_RESULT;
            }
```

So what's happening is that for several transactions that are picked up by the job I get a Kafka null result error message because of the above code so I went into debug to see what was happening putting a breakpoint at where messagingResultCode is set.

But when I evaluated "kafkaWriter.getKafkaStatusCode() == null" it showed as "(boolean) false" in Spring Tools Suite. When looking at the KafkaStatusCode it shows as "C" so definitely not null, but it still went into the code anyway.

All getKafkaStatusCode() does is return a String:

```
public String getKafkaStatusCode() {
    return kafkaStatusCode;
}
```

This only ever happens on the first job that's been run on the server (I'm using Liberty) and on all subsequent runs the code behaves as expected.

I've tried initialising the String messagingResultCode to null, "" and a default value but the same thing happens every time.

Thanks

Comment: The situation you describe is obviously impossible, and you haven't provided enough for anybody to try to reproduce it.

Comment: either you have uncompiled code and it differs from the running code, or you set the `messagingResultCode`somewhere else

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I agree it should be impossible which is why it's confusing me. It's a large program so I wouldn't expect anyone to try and recreate it. Just curious if anyone has ever come across something like this when running Spring batch jobs on Liberty...I suspect that might be something to do with the issue as the code looks fine and it works as expected on all runs after the first.

Comment: besides the uncompiled code , if the code is in the jar,i guess another possiable case is that the source lib is different from the class lib.

Comment: @jhamon + AFu Thanks...yes, it appears logically impossible to do what I'm seeing so probably something like that. I'll look into it more.

Comment: ..or: (time/) asynchronity *is* in place ;) (I.e. debugging influences the outcome;)

Comment: @xerx593 It happens when running normally too and on our dev servers.

Answer (score 0):

".or: (time/) asynchronity is in place ;) (I.e. debugging influences the outcome;) – xerx593 3 hours ago"

@xerx593 You were right, the debugger wasn't showing me the correct value which I found after putting in some extra logging and running it in non-debug.

Turns out you can't trust the debugger all the time :)

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer actually, but rather a comment. Would be nice to see how did you solve the problem with some details.

Comment: The debugger was showing the status code coming back from the Kafka producer as "C" which is what it's set to if we get a successful response back. So I put some logging just after the status code is set which just prints out the code and then ran the job in non debug. The logs showed that the status code was null as for some reason messages weren't being sent successfully. So the debugger wasn't showing the correct value coming back...not sure why.